# How can $A/P^c$ be viewed as a subring of $B/P$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, localization

Let $f : A \to B$ be a commutative ring hom.  If for ideal $J$ in $B$ we define $J^c = f^{-1}(J)$ and we let $P$ be a prime ideal, then how is $A/P^c$ viewed as a subring of $B/P$?  Especially since $A \to B$ is not necess. injective.

This is out of Matsumura's *Commutative Algebra*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A\to B$ isn't injective. $A/P^c\to B/P$, on the other hand, is.

Consider the composite homomorphism $A\to B\to B/P$, and what the kernel of this homomorphism is.

Comment: This makes sense now.  $g f (a) = 0 \implies f(a) \in P$.

Comment: @EyesOnBud ... which again is equivalent to $a\in P^c$, by definition of $^c$. That's right.